# SendMessage from injected code to BackGround script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, content-script

I have injected a script (stored on localhost) into a webpage.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: 'js/content.js', /* my content script */   }, () => {
    connect(show_floater) //this is where I call my function to establish a connection     });
});
```

The above code is how I injected my code from my background script.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: "am I connected?" });
```

This code is the part that troubles me. I am trying to send a message to the background script. I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of runtime.sendMessage(optional string extensionId, any message, optional object options, optional function responseCallback): chrome.runtime.sendMessage() called from a webpage must specify an Extension ID (string) for its first argument.
> at elemRelease (test.js:93)

So what I tried is to add the extension ID:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('jlebkcopkekjggkknplilgflekifmjkp', { text: "am I connected?" });
```

The error goes away but the listener in bg script does not get triggered by this call

This is what my bg script looks like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        console.log('connected?');
        if (msg.text == "am I connected?") {
            // do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Judging by "script stored on localhost" you're doing something *really* weird there like maybe running these scripts outside of extension environment, which is *the only reason* why the first sendMessage could fail with that particular error message. Or maybe you're just looking at the old error in chrome://extensions page which doesn't auto-remove old errors

Comment: @wOxxOm the reason I am doing it from the localhost (in future it will be on an actual server) is that I want the extension to be injected in the page so that in order to update the extension I just need to change the code on my server and the user only needs to re-load the page without having to update anything.

Comment: Without seeing how exactly you're doing it, all I can repeat is that extensions don't work like this.

Comment: @wOxxOm I know I am a nobody to you but could I pick your brain on the matter? I really would appreciate it. We could use discord or a streaming service to help